# Selenium with UWP apps?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, uwp, .net-standard

I want to use Selenium in my UWP app, but since UWP's runtime is WRC,

I can't install Selenium.WebDriver package (it targets .NET Framework 3.5 & 4.0) or CoreCompat.Selenium.WebDriver (it targets .NET Standard 1.5, and UWP does not support it right now).

The reasons mentioned above, are the same reasons why can't I use a .NET Standard 1.4 (as mentioned before, UWP supports up-to .NET Standard 1.4 class library).

I tried using a Portable Class Library, which targets .NET Framework and UWP, but after installing the Selenium.WebDriver package, I couldn't access it (I did reference it).

Am I doing some thing wrong? Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium currently doesn't support UWP apps. And UWP .NET Native support will go from 1.4 to 2.0 (fall 2017).

I suggest using [appium.io](http://appium.io/) to test UWP apps, which also uses the WebDriver protocol you're using with Selenium.

Comment: Appium is not compatible with UWP.

Comment: Yes it is. https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/writing-running-appium/windows-app-testing/

Comment: I mean, you can't use the selenium and call appium functions from UWP.
You need .NET 4.5 for appium, and I have no way to call .NET 4.5 methods from UWP.